# Two simple sorting algorithms in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

For a personal programming challenge, I wanted to try writing simple bubble sort and insertion sort functions in Python 3. I haven't looked at the standard pseudo-code, I just read about how they worked. Are these good implementations?

```
def bubble_sort(array):
    """ 
    Sorts array using a bubble sort. 

    >>> bubble_sort([43, 10, 100, 24, 1, 6, 10, 3])
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 10, 24, 43, 100]
    """
    array2 = array[:] # Save a copy, so that original is not mutated
    last_index = len(array) - 1 # Iterate up to this position
    while last_index > 0:
        for i in range(last_index):
            a, b = array2[i], array2[i + 1] # Consecutive numbers in array
            if a > b:
                array2[i], array2[i + 1] = b, a # Swap positions
        last_index -= 1 # A new number has bubbled up, no need to inspect it again
    return array2


def insertion_sort(array):
    """ 
    Sorts array using an insertion sort. 

    >>> insertion_sort([43, 10, 100, 24, 1, 6, 10, 3])
    [1, 3, 6, 10, 10, 24, 43, 100]
    """
    sorted_array = []
    for a in array:
        # Loop backwards through sorted_array
        for i, b in reversed(list(enumerate(sorted_array))):
            if a > b:
                sorted_array.insert(i + 1, a) # Insert a to the right of b
                break
        else:
            # a is less than all numbers in sorted_array
            sorted_array.insert(0, a) # Add a to beginning of list
    return sorted_array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docstrings and doctests are nice.  I would prefer a more explicit description of the behaviour: "Return a *copy* of the array, sorted using the bubble sort algorithm."  Typically, if you're implementing these sorting algorithms as an exercise, you would perform the sorting in place.

---

In `bubble_sort()`, the `while last_index > 0` loop would be written more idiomatically as:

```
for last_index in range(len(array) - 1, 0, -1):
    …
```

---

In `insertion_sort()`, the `reversed(list(enumerate(sorted_array)))` would be making temporary copies of `sorted_array`.  I would therefore consider it an improper implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: I see the point about `reversed(list(enumerate(sorted_array)))` creating temporary copies. Is there a way that could be avoided?

Comment: Use a `range()` over the indices you want to traverse, like you did with `bubble_sort()`.